# manipulation the original source of a file or video url like youtube player or cloud file download sites

Tags: django, python-3.x

if we see big websites like youtube, google drive, facebook, cloud file download sites, etc., then we will find that every link file, video, image or whatever, then the original file link will not be seen for example videos on youtube, even if we inspect the element and see the source on the video player it isn't visible, the link is just written:

```
src = "https://www.youtube.com/94118230-9dbf-4207-a098-de7a7ccdf7f6"
```

without any real address or file extension like .mp4 or others. can anyone help explain how to engineer this and whether django can handle engineering like this?

Answer (score 0):

First point: an url doesn't have to point to a file. What happens when some url is requested is up to the HTTP server serving the url. Serving files from the server's filesystem is the basic default for most HTTP servers (static sites), but that's just one of the possibilies, it can as well be executing a CGI script, delegating to a pool of long running processes (typical Python wsgi app), whatever...

Second point: files extensions are mostly cosmetic. You can have a file name without any extension directly served by Apache, and you can have an url with a filename extension that is actually served by some script or other program dynamicall generating content.

IOW, there's absolutely no relation between what the url looks like and how the response is built, and "original file link" doesn't mean anything, and the youtube url you posted IS as much of a "real address" than any other url.

> can anyone help explain how to engineer this

It's impossible to answer this question, at least not with a one-size-fits-all answer. If all you want is to serve a static file without extension, just rename the file without the extension, possibly tweak your HTTP server config so that it correctly handles the case, and you're done.

> whether django can handle engineering like this

Any techno that is *not* able to "handle engineering like this" is either prehistoric or fundamentally broken.

I strongy suggest you (seriously) read about the HTTP protocol and learn to set up and configure a standard HTTP server (Apache comes to mind). Only then will it make sense to worry about specific technos (Django or else).